# How to get a torrent file link that can be downloaded?

Tags: html, torrent

I am creating a movie website for a project. In the website I'm going to add movies download links that can be downloaded via torrents. I have seen in some websites that they use torcache.net to provide download links. And my quesion is how to create a magnet link, or how to get a torrent file link that can embed in a html file from websites like torcache.net...

Comment: What is it about putting up a plain old torrent link that doesn't suit your purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just copy and pasting the magnet link from a regular torrent indexing site?

What is going to differentiate your website from a plain old torrent indexer like thepiratebay?

Making a link in html is simply a matter of:

```
<a href="torcache.com/torrent/ID">text</a>
```

Could you please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I think the gentleman is asking how, using magnet links, to download the data via torrent network in the application and serve is to the user.

There is a javascript library called [WebTorrent](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent) that uses WebRTC protocol to transmit data in the browser to other browsers. You can use magnet links or .torrent files.

> In the browser, WebTorrent uses WebRTC (data channels) for
>   peer-to-peer transport. It can be used without browser plugins,
>   extensions, or installations. It's Just JavaScript™. Note: WebTorrent
>   does not support UDP/TCP peers in browser.

You can see a demo of it where a video clip is streamed in via torrent and after it buffers up a bit, starts playing a short movie. You can also see a visual of the nodes connecting and disconnecting, which is quite cool - https://webtorrent.io

Bonus:

If I want to share large files (> 10Mb) with multiple people I use [file.pizza](https://file.pizza/) implementation.